# Tennis racket theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

According to Tennis racket theorem, the rotation around the second principal axis
 become unstable. Then, what is the 1st, 2nd and 3rd principal axis of this object ([video](https://twitter.com/i/status/1212326329103704066))?

Comment: The Dzhanibekov effect explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VPfZ_XzisU&t=590s

Comment: He explains the axes starting about 3:50 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VPfZ_XzisU&t=590s

Comment: I understand it. Thank you.